# postgres main role is not postgres, how can I set it up to postgress

Tags: postgresql

In terminal, when I write psql it login to "Coyr". I want "postgres" to be the main user and have all the attributes. How can I accomplish that?

[image]

Comment: The role `postgres` is a superuser so it has all rights. Not sure what more you want and why?

Comment: I can see postgres as a role but if I run "sudo -u postgres psql" it shows:
sudo: unknown user: postgres
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin. Typically "postgres" is the main user but it is not happening in my case. Everytime I donwload a librery it get errors

Comment: sudo is about changing your OS user, not your PostgreSQL user.

Comment: What OS and version? How did you install Postgres? Do you see postgres when you do `ls /home/`?

Comment: Os is macOS Catalina version 10.15.7.
I installed Postgres using brew. When I do `ls /home/` it keeps showing the actual folder where I am

Comment: Well I guess that is how a Homebrew install of Postgres works. From here [Homebrew](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Homebrew): '...it basically sets up a single "admin" user with your username...'.  So you just do `psql postgres` in your home directory.  Looks like you have already created a `postgres` role as superuser, so then you could do `psql -d postgres -U postgres`. The thing is the database cluster has been created with the role `coyr` as the default superuser, so you will be fighting that.

Comment: In other words: homebrew is braindead. (BTW: most of the Postgres developers use OSX)

Comment: I will come back to this, for an specific case I will continue in this moment with this user. Thank you

Comment: @wildplasser. Homebrew is not brain dead, there is no requirement that the superuser/cluster owner be postgres. Per docs [initdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html) 'It is really not important what the superuser's name is, but one might choose to keep the customary name postgres...'. Homebrew chooses to run as the user installing, that is all. FYI, the developers build their own Postgres from source and test on the build farm which cover all the OS variations supported.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you ran `initdb` as user `coyr` without the `-U` option, and now you want to rename the bootstrap superuser.

That is easy:

- drop the user `postgres` you created
- create a new superuser `maxi`
- connect as `maxi` and run

  ```
  ALTER ROLE coyr RENAME TO postgres;
  ```
- connect as `postgres` and

  ```
  DROP ROLE maxi;
  ```

By renaming `coyr` will have lost its password, so if you need one, you have to set it again.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz that make sense. I have found that usually in some repos people use "postgres" as the username. What is the best practice?. Do you have some reference about Postgres configuration in Mac?

Comment: Yes, it is an informal standard to have the bootstrap superuser called `postgres`, so I would call this "best practice".